# Change host machine's hosts file from docker

Tags: docker, nginx, virtualhost, hosts

My idea is to setup a web development environment using Docker for Mac with a web based control panel to manage the virtual hosts. First I'll need to launch the machine binding the host's port 80 to the docker's port 80 and so on.

That web control panel should be able to add a virtual host to the Docker's Nginx configuration. That's easy. But opening that virtual host in the host machine's browser doesn't work because it's not on the hosts file.

Is it possible to update the host machine's hosts file from the docker machine? I don't want to edit it manually or use Nginx on the host machine as a reverse proxy somehow.